# Perl - How do I resize and annotate with Image::Magick with a "system" call?

Tags: perl, imagemagick, annotate

```
Image::Magick

system("convert $imageurl $new");
system("convert $new -geometry 480x360 -blur .8 -quality 100 $new");
```

and

```
system("convert $imageurl $new");
system("convert $new -resize 480x360 -blur .8 -quality 100 $new");
```

Both the above work fine but, I don't see a visible diff between geometry and resize. Read up on it, over my head, it works so, I will learn as i go here.

For annotating, the below works fine:

```
my $image;
my $test_text="testies123"; 
$image=Image::Magick->new;
my $x=$image->Read(filename=>"$new");
$x=$image->Annotate(text=>"$test_text",font=>'Candice.ttf',fill=>'#5BADFF',pointsize=>'14',gravity=>'SouthEast', x=>5, y=>5);
$x=$image->Write(filename=>'new_file.jpg'); undef $image;
```

(The $vars in above examples were obviously declared previously.)

What I am trying to do is combine it all into one shorter routine.

Like:

```
system("convert $new -geometry 480x360 -blur .8 -quality 100 -annotate -text testies123 -font Candice -fill blue -pointsize 14  -gravity SouthEast -x 5 -y 5 $new");
```

I have tried several variations of the above and also just attempted to annotate via system() but, I just cannot figure this out.

Perhaps there is even a better way all together?
Thanks in advance for teaching this old dog another trick.

Comment: (1) why do you need a shorter routine, and (2) why not just use Image::Magick to do the conversion as well as the annotating, instead of the command line tools?

Answer (score 1):

You may read documentation to clear arguments of `-annotate` option http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#annotate

```
system("convert $new -geometry 480x360 -blur .8 -quality 100 -font Candice -fill blue -pointsize 14  -gravity SouthEast -annotate +5+5 testies123 $new")
```